# onActivityResult isn't being triggered

Tags: android, android-intent, startactivityforresult

I'm trying to pass data from one activity to another however the onActivityResult is not being triggered. With my startup activity which is called MainActivity, I'm able to view an image gallery which will then trigger the onActivityResult with this piece of code.

```
  Intent i = new Intent(
                    Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

            startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
```

From another Acitivity I have this piece of code

```
 gridLayout.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent intent =new Intent();
            setResult(RESULT_OK,intent);
            intent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("someData",id);
            finish();

        }
    });
```

This will also call onActivityResult in MainActivity just fine however this next line of code will not.

```
   gridLayout.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("someData",id);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
        }
    });
```

I have looked into the manifest files and everything is set correctly. I've seen people suggest things such as turning android:noHistory="false" however I have none of these set in my manifest. It's very simple and looks like this.

```
  <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true">

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/CustomTheme"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ImageRollActivity"
        android:theme="@style/GridTheme"
        android:label=" Image Roll"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
        >
    </activity>
```

If anyone has any insight as to why this isn't being triggered that would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the second one you are calling `startActivityForResult()` instead of `setResult()` (as in the first example).

Calling `startActivityForResult()` will start the Activity which means it will be recreated and go through the [Activity lifecycle](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwih6s_S1KnRAhVp7YMKHcsDCOMQFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fguide%2Fcomponents%2Factivities%2Factivity-lifecycle.html&usg=AFQjCNEKLsQfQ2RWiIjYbDLOfWAyFISW1Q&sig2=za00wwnzaU1GL9TBGKfq8g).

`setResult()` is what you need for it to call `onActivityResult()`.

Comment: I've read that Activity lifecycle before but never for startActivityForResult. After reading that section I feel like an idiot for asking the question now haha, but thanks for the response!

Comment: No problem. It happens :D